# Using PLINK.EXE how to startup tail -f logfile.log | grep myself

Tags: ssh, grep, tail, putty

I'm using a Windows command file:

```
@Echo Off
MODE con:cols=5000 lines=80
cmd /k "title & x:\dir\Putty\PLINK.EXE -ssh name@connection tail -f /opt/dir1/dir2/Blabla_Debug.log"
```

This works like a charm. It's executable from my client and gives me a tail on the logfile and a decent header in the cmd-box (so I know what I'm looking at).

But now I want to execute a grep on the logfile.

I've tried to add '| grep text' (without the quotes) but that results in an error (in the command box): 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

So what I've tried is:

```
cmd /k "title & x:\dir\Putty\PLINK.EXE -ssh name@connection tail -f /opt/dir1/dir2/Blabla_Debug.log | grep text"
```

Comment: you need to get the grep to be part of the ssh command; wrap single quotes around the tail and grep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the argument of the `title` command is missed

```
cmd.exe /k "title dnslogger & PLINK.EXE -ssh root@xenial.local tail -f /var/log/dnsmasq.log | grep -v DHCP"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, unfortunately that doesn't help. Still the same error.

Comment: Windows Version and Version of cmd.exe? Please post the output from ```cmd.exe /k ver```

Comment: I'm using: Windows 2008 R2
Result of cmd.exe /k ver is [Version 6.1.7601]

Comment: Create a textfile with the complete shell command, for example ``logintail.sh`` with the command line as content ``tail -f /var/log/mail.log | stdbuf -o0 grep Login:``. The plink command is now ``PLINK.EXE -batch -ssh -agent -i mykey.ppk -m logintail.sh you@yourserver.local``. It works on 2008R2.

Comment: nice!
Creating a script.sh file on the Windows site was something I didn't think of. It's working. Even with the cmd /k "title .... feature.